# He is thinking crazy again

Tags: riddle

"I am thinking of a gesture", said Grandpa

> "It becomes powerful when you turn it upside down
>
> But gets weaker when you turn it sideways!
>
> Then again, gets stronger when you turn it sideways to the other side"

Then he smiled and said, "You will find a lot of it in Italy"

What is he thinking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe the Grandpa is talking about:

> [image]
>  As mentioned by @Tom, this may be the "spaghetti" gesture (as shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q36oC.jpg)
>
>  Alternatively: (thanks to @DEEM)
>  [image]
>  which is the Italian "Can I have a cigarette, please?" gesture

It becomes powerful when you turn it upside down

> [image]
>  An offensive (powerful) gesture used mostly in UK.
>
>  Alternatively: (thanks to @DEEM)
>  [image]
>  Which looks like "^" which means "To the POWER of" making it "more powerful".

But gets weaker when you turn it sideways!

> [image]
>  Because it is the "less than" symbol. Less = weaker

Then again, gets stronger when you turn it sideways to the other side

> [image]
> By analogy - "greater than"

Comment: Perhaps 'upside down' here could be taken to mean 'back to front' like a peace sign or Churchill's V for Victory? Both pretty iconic political gestures...

Comment: On the other hand it may be the rot13(svefg bs gurfr yvxr vairegrq-I. Gura hcfvqr qbja vf gur I-sbe-ivpgbel fvta.) [Top left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q36oC.jpg)

Comment: I believe that's it @Tom. Thanks for finding the meaning of the gesture #1

Comment: @oleslaw Think about inverted V which is ^. A sign that means "To the POWER of" Makes it powerful?

Comment: @DEEM This actually matches the general topic of this answer too.

Comment: YUP. You are right. Also V is a ROMAN numeral